# using XML files to store layout of platformer blocks

Tags: c#, xml, xna, levels

Hi all thanks for looking and hopefully helping me out on this as i am completely stuck!

I am coding a game in XNA. Platform game, very simple for now. I have the player all sorted can jump, walk, run and is animated for each action. I have scrolling background which loops two copies of a 8-bit street location. I also have a powerup which currently just increases the players score. I have also created a PlatformBlock class which is a simple texture and a position (oh and a bool to see if contains powerup).

Anyway, my question is... I want to store the positions for my blocks in a XML document. But I am totally unsure of the format to type the XML in (eh.  ... etc... I'm lost), I'm also unsure of how to call it from within XNA so that it will place the List blocks accordingly.

Please can someone type it in simple plain english as I have browsed literrally 15-20 tutorials on this matter and still cannot even start to add it into my game. I once a few months ago did manage to get this up and running for a breakout style game and in the end it worked well but I have no longer got that file, cant find the specific tutorial i used. In other words....PLEASE HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

Depend how complex game will be. You can simply store level like this in .txt file, where **x** is platform and **.** blank space.

```
...................
..xxxxxx......xxxx.
...................
.......xxxxxxx.....
...................
```

but also you can store this into XML:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Position>0,10</Position>
    <Name>Wall</Name>
    <Rotation>0</Rotation>
    <ImageName>-</ImageName>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Position>10,10</Position>
    <Name>Wall</Name>
    <Rotation>0</Rotation>
    <ImageName>-</ImageName>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

but in any way, you actually need to create "game level editor" using your game engine (or any other), and after that you create a game. choice is yours how you will store game level.

Comment: Ive all the classes set up and I made a new class called LevelCreator. In this class all I realy want to do it pull in X coords that will be fed to each new PlatformBlock in my List as they are created the next one gets assigned. So all I have to do to change the layout is change the coords in my text/xml file. Text would obviously seem easier and Im a beginner here. So this is how simple for now: I want 10 blocks, all will have Y coord of say '400',but then each one I set a X coord like 100,200,400,500,800,900.. so on.. Please can you help me know how to implement this? manythanks 4 all help